# how to access application.get from generic handler

Tags: asp.net, generic-handler, application-state

I have a global.asax in which I define some variables that I want to be available throughout the application, such as a class to handle certain database requests. In an aspx page, I can access these variables/objects using for example in Visual Basic:

```
dim dataMan as clsData = application.get("dataGofer")
```

My question: is it possible to call this from a generic handler (.ashx file)? If so, can you please show me a code snippet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Context` parameter of `ProcessRequest` method through which you can access the page objects.

```
Dim value=context.Application.Get("key")
```